# Extracting text in custom tags use Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, custom-tags

This is a [web page](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15721472) for a paper. There're some useful information to extract.

I want to extract title, author and abstract of this paper. So I wrote following code:

```
class PublicationSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "publications"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15721472',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for publication in response.css('div.rprt.abstract'):
            yield {
                'title': publication.css('h1::text').extract_first(),
                'author': publication.css('div.auths > a::text').extract(),
                'abstract': publication.css('div.abstr abstracttext::text').extract(),
                'doi': publication.css('div.aux a::text').extract_first(),
            }
```

Unfortunately, the code above could not return the right content. It seems that the `abstracttext` element cannot be recognized by Scrapy.

I tried to replace `abstracttext` with `h4`, and the script went well.

So how can I extract the content in `abstracttext`?

Comment: Your code works for me. try `scrapy shell <url>` then `response.css('div.abstr abstracttext::text')` and the results are there.  It could be that for some reason your `lxml` backend is rendering the answer differently, what operating system are you running? Can you also try `pip show lxml` and tell us the version?

Comment: @Granitosaurus Yes, it works in `scrapy shell` but not works in Python script.

Comment: Your spider works for me. Could you post your `settings.py`? Do you have any middlewares or pipelines enabled? Could you also post whole run log? You can do that by `scrapy crawl spider 2>&1 > output.log`

Comment: @Granitosaurus There's no other files such as `settings.py`. The `crawl` command said: `Scrapy 1.2.1 - no active project Unknown command: crawl`.

Comment: How are you even running the spider?

Comment: @Granitosaurus Yes, I ran with this command: `scrapy runspider PublicationSpider.py -o publications.json`.

Comment: Your code runs fine: http://pastebin.com/atp34920 . Do you have a different output?

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution by simply using `lxml`:

```
from lxml import html
from requests import get as getRequest

htmlPage = getRequest('https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15721472')
htmlTree = html.fromstring(htmlPage.content)

title               = htmlTree.xpath('//div[@class="rprt abstract"]/h1/text()')
authors             = htmlTree.xpath('//div[@class="auths"]/a/text()')
doi                 = htmlTree.xpath('//dl[@class="rprtid"]/dd/a/text()')
abstractHeadings    = htmlTree.xpath('//div[@class="abstr"]/div/h4/text()')
abstractTexts       = htmlTree.xpath('//div[@class="abstr"]/div/p/abstracttext/text()')
```

Reference:

- http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/

Answer (score -1):

you can use following xpath for get value.

```
title = publication.xpath("//div[@class='rprt_all']/div/h1/text()").extract()
```

Comment: It works for `h1` but not works for the tag named `abstracttext`